# Add a second router to extend my network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

My household actually spans two houses with a little courtyard in between them. I have set up my main router so it connects the first house to the internet. I guess that by placing another router in the second house, and connecting the two to each other with ethernet I can extend my network.
My question is, do I need to configure the extra router?

Comment: You might want to disable NAT, DHCP etc. on the second to run it in "slave mode", as if it wasn't there. Then give the Wifi an identical name and password to enable roaming.

Comment: what does this mean?

Comment: Some tutorials: http://www.tested.com/tech/298-how-to-use-an-old-router-to-expand-your-wi-fi-network/ | http://www.howtogeek.com/104469/how-to-extend-your-wi-fi-network-with-simple-access-points/ | http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www.labnol.org/software/add-router-to-wireless-network/19716/&gws_rd=cr&ei=ud3qVYfuM4bLyAOy2aqQBA

Comment: What kind of routers do you use? (brand, type)? Is the setup default or did you change settings in the routers?

Comment: @CoDEmanX It's usually called "bridge mode" not "slave mode".